# Qt QItemDelegate Commit data and close Editor on mouse leave the view widget (listView)

Tags: c++, qt, listview, mouseleave, qitemdelegate

I had a problem with calling off the editor of my listView, when mouse left it. I have managed to solve my problem. It was not obvious to me, so I've decided to post my solution:

In delegate header file Ive created a editor widget pointer, and in constructor, I gave him the value Q_NULLPTR.

```
//in header file of Delegate
mutable QWidget *myCustomWidget;

//in the source file of Delegate
MyItemDelegate::MyItemDelegate(QObject *parent) : QStyledItemDelegate(parent),
  myCustomWidget(Q_NULLPTR)
{
}
```

then in createEditor:

```
QWidget *MyItemDelegate::createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
myCustomWidget= new KontaktForm(parent);
myCustomWidget->autoFillBackground();

return myCustomWidget;
}
```

in MyListView header file I've created a signal saveToModelFromEditor(); and emited the signal in

```
void MyListView::leaveEvent(QEvent *event)
{
emit saveToModelFromEditor();

QListView::leaveEvent(event);
}
```

The function to commitData to the model and close the editor, if someone wants it to close:

```
void MyItemDelegate::commitAndSaveData()
{
if(kontaktForm!=Q_NULLPTR){

// after testing the UI I've decided, that the editor should remain open, and just commit data

emit commitData(kontaktForm);

//    emit closeEditor(kontaktForm);
}
}
```

Finally I've used signal and slot mechanism to connect signal from listView to slot in the editor

```
   connect(treeView,SIGNAL(saveToModelFromEditor()),itemDelegate,SLOT(commitAndSaveData()));
```

I had help from a different comunity (VoidRealms facebook group).

Hope this helps someone here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In delegate header file Ive created a editor widget pointer, and in constructor, I gave him the value Q_NULLPTR.

```
 //in header file of Delegate
 mutable QWidget *myCustomWidget;

 //in the source file of Delegate
 MyItemDelegate::MyItemDelegate(QObject *parent) : QStyledItemDelegate(parent),
   myCustomWidget(Q_NULLPTR)
 {
 }
```

then in createEditor:

```
 QWidget *MyItemDelegate::createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
 {
 myCustomWidget= new KontaktForm(parent);
 myCustomWidget->autoFillBackground();

 return myCustomWidget;
 }
```

in MyListView header file I've created a signal saveToModelFromEditor(); and emited the signal in

```
 void MyListView::leaveEvent(QEvent *event)
 {
 emit saveToModelFromEditor();

 QListView::leaveEvent(event);
 }
```

The function to commitData to the model and close the editor, if someone wants it to close:

```
 void MyItemDelegate::commitAndSaveData()
 {
 if(kontaktForm!=Q_NULLPTR){

 // after testing the UI I've decided, that the editor should remain open, and just commit data

 emit commitData(kontaktForm);

 //    emit closeEditor(kontaktForm);
 }
 }
```

Finally I've used signal and slot mechanism to connect signal from listView to slot in the editor

```
    connect(treeView,SIGNAL(saveToModelFromEditor()),itemDelegate,SLOT(commitAndSaveData()));
```

I had help from a different comunity (VoidRealms facebook group).

Hope this helps someone here.